# How do I cycle through the camera views?

Tags: camera, shortcut, scene

When reviewing the existing cameras of a scene, 
is there a way to quickly cycle through the views of all cameras?

Answer (score 11):

You can try by binding the cameras to the markers. In the timeline, press <kbd>M</kbd> to add marker in specified frames. You can rename that frame by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.

Assuming you have 2 cameras on viewport, then add two marker on timeline (adjust location of the marker diferently, ie : `marker 1 : 1-20`, marker `2 : 21-50`). Now select the first camera, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> to set as active camera, make sure first marker selected, then in timeline press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to bind active camera to first marker.

Select the second marker, then set second camera as active again <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>, hover the mouse on the timeline and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.

Now, when you start the animation <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, the camera should switch between first and second based on marker position.

Comment: If you just want to switch views without changing cameras on the timeline, just use ctrl+numpad0 after selecting the camera you want to view from.

Answer (score 2):

run the following script:

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
currentcam = bpy.context.scene.camera
setcam = False

for ob in scene.objects:
    if ob.type == 'CAMERA':
        if ob == currentcam:
            setcam = True
        elif setcam:
            bpy.context.scene.camera = ob
            break

if currentcam == bpy.context.scene.camera:      
    for ob in scene.objects:
        if ob.type == 'CAMERA':
            bpy.context.scene.camera = ob
            break
```