# how to take images with multiple cameras with Script?

Tags: rendering, camera

To be clear i want a script, which produces what i am describing below.
I want to iterate through all the cameras in my scene where each one renderes an image. I can do this manually by rendering with active camera, then set another camera to active, and then render again.

I have five cameras in my scene and i am going to be using this scene a lot.
in reality the question might be more about setting a camera to active with script.

Comment: might be easier to control: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23121/is-it-possible-to-set-the-output-name-based-on-the-current-timeline-marker/23145#23145

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to edit the `os.path.join` to get an OS independent tmp directory or set something else.

```
import bpy
import os

scene = bpy.context.scene

for ob in scene.objects:
    if ob.type == 'CAMERA':
        bpy.context.scene.camera = ob
        print('Set camera %s' % ob.name )
        file = os.path.join("C:/tmp", ob.name )
        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = file
        bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )
```

Comment: I am not a python genius,  why would i need to do so?

Comment: @Artmole the drive letter C: wouldn't work on Linux and MacOs or you want another output folder. The rest is straight forward loop over all objects in the scene, check whether the object is a camera if so set it as camera, setup the filepath where the render should be stored and write the render to a file with the name of the camera.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a still, you could make it into an animation where the only thing that changes is the active camera, and render it as an animation (see [How can I make a camera the active one?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one) for how to animate the active camera property)