# Is it possible to set the Output name based on the current Timeline marker?

Tags: python, scripting

I've got a scene with timeline markers. Example: "Bob", "John" etc.

I want to set the Output file name to match these markers, so that I can hit Render Animation and have Blender change the output file names to match the timeline markers. 
So when the playhead reaches the "bob" timeline marker, the output filename is changed to "bob.png"

[image]

How would I go about making a Python script to automate this?

Comment: Sure! http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=82275

As you can see, I simply need to change the file name based on the current timeline marker.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following script renders every frame in the timeline *if it is a marker assigned to it*. It uses the existing output file path and and the current marker name as output file name.

[image]

```
import bpy
import os

# get the scene
scn = bpy.context.scene

# get the output path
output_path = scn.render.filepath

# iterate through markers and render
for k, m in scn.timeline_markers.items():  
    frame = m.frame
    marker_name = m.name
    scn.frame_set(frame)
    scn.render.filepath = os.path.join(output_path, marker_name + ".jpg")
    bpy.ops.render.render( write_still=True )

bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output_path
```

[**.blend**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33818)

Comment: Brilliant!

Well done. Works a treat.

Thanks

Comment: Still works 5 years later, in blender 2.92!!