# for Loop stop with when previewing render progress

Tags: rendering, scripting

I have been attempting to create a simple add-on to assist non-3D colleagues.

Part of the plugin uses markers as filename during the render sequence.

Below is the code that I use to render and save the image.

```
bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT', write_still=True)
```

But 'INVOKE_DEFAULT' stops the for loop. If I remove the code I don't get to see the render progress.

Is there a solution to view the render progress and save the images?

Here is the section of the code I use render and save the images with the marker names.

```
def execute(self, context):
    # get the scene
    scn = bpy.context.scene

    # get the output path
    output_path = scn.render.filepath

    # iterate through markers and render
    for k, m in scn.timeline_markers.items():  
        frame = m.frame
        marker_name = m.name
        scn.frame_set(frame)
        scn.render.filepath = os.path.join(output_path, marker_name + "." + scn.render.image_settings.file_format)
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

    #reset the output path
    scn.render.filepath = output_path

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

Comment: Funny, looks like my take on [Is it possible to set the Output name based on the current Timeline marker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23145/3710) 5 years ago :) Anyway, if nothing has changed in latest versions of blender it's tricky making that work properly due to the nature of the render operator. You need a modal operator and catch all potential errors: [example](https://github.com/p2or/blender-loom/blob/master/loom.py#L2129).

Comment: It is! My version didn't work as good. 
Thanks for the assist. I been working on a proof of concept to implement blender in a manufacturing company. Was meant to be simple.

Comment: Cool, if I have time I'm going to implement an operator for [loom](https://github.com/p2or/blender-loom/blob/master/loom.py) in the next weeks which allows rendering the cameras based on the markers. If you have time, I'd appreciate your help on that. Btw: I don't think you need `scn.render.image_settings.file_format`, `jpg` as it was, is just a placeholder and will be overwritten by the file format given in the ui anyway. Cheers! @Sharl

Comment: I can give you my feedback but I am not a programmer just a hack :P

Comment: The plugin am working, is just to set the markers as filenames. Everything else is custom UI layout for focused workflow.