# How to set the Alt+S default filename other than untitled.png?

Tags: rendering

I need to set the rendered filename (Alt+S) to something else than `untitled.png`. However I can't find the setting as displayed here [Is it possible to set the Output name based on the current Timeline marker?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23121/99884)

[image: pic!]
[image: pic!]

Comment: With Alt+S you will save the active image in the UV Editor or Image Editor, not the rendered image. Go to the UV/Image Editor and rename the picture there.

Comment: Setting as displayed in linked  image is in the output panel of the output tab, the icon  that looks like a printer (3 down from top)  @FFeller lol didn't notice the alt-s.