# how to automate the render save in blender with python

Tags: python, rendering, saving

hi guys i want to render a body in blender from all sides. i wrote a code where the camera rotates around a body in steps and renders one image each time. but i don't know how to make the code change the name of the file. so that each photo has a different name, because the program always overwrites the photos.

```
import bpy

#Kamera erstellen
def camera_add():
    bpy.ops.object.camera_add(location=(0, 10, 0),  scale=(1, 1, 1))
    bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[0] = -1.5708
    bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[1] = 3.14159
    
camera_add()

#Objekt (CUBE) erstellen
def körper_plazieren(x,y):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
    bpy.context.object.location[0] = x
    
körper_plazieren(0,1)



# Rotation mit rendern
i=0
for i in range(5):
    bpy.context.object.location[0] = 0
    bpy.data.scenes[0].render.filepath =  '...Desktop/Blender/testnew'
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
    bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[0] = i * 1.5708
```

i want it to render images by eachrotation, but save the image with different names each , so it dont overwrite the images.

Comment: I think you can just replace
bpy.data.scenes[0].render.filepath =  '...Desktop/Blender/testnew'
with
bpy.data.scenes[0].render.filepath =  f"...Desktop/Blender/testnew{i}"
or something similar to this.

Comment: Why not just animate the camera about the body, and render an image sequence?

Comment: I'd suggest, create all cameras in the first place, then render. Also see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8850/how-to-take-images-with-multiple-cameras-with-script, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8850/how-to-take-images-with-multiple-cameras-with-script and there is more... e.g. alternatively you can also create markers: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23121/is-it-possible-to-set-the-output-name-based-on-the-current-timeline-marker/23145#23145