# Changing the position of the camera using python script and then rendering using the new location

Tags: python, rendering

I am currently using blender version 2.92 and am trying to change the camera position using a python script.
I am passing the coordinates for the camera using a JSON file and the snippet for the same is as :

```
"camera_locations":[
    [
      2.576395273208618,
      -4.465750694274902,
      1.094475507736206
    ],
    [
     100.87639527320862,
      -9.465750694274902,
      400.094475507736206
    ]
```

I am creating a function and passing the camera object and the camera locations (that I have read from the JSON file ) as parameters. Further, I am then trying to change the camera location and render. Following is the code snippet:

```
def render(camera_locations,object):
    
    camera_location=object.location
    print("the current camera position is as: ", camera_location)
    for locations in camera_locations:
        count=0
        for location in locations:
            object.location[count]=location
            count+=1
            if(count==3):
               count=0
        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath=output_path+str(i)
        bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport=True,write_still=True)
```

However, when I render I do not see any changes in the images with respect to the camera location. The images look identical.
I have tried printing the above variables and those **do** show the updated values.
I am not sure what I am missing here. Can someone guide me with this or suggest a better way to tackle the problem?

Comment: @brockmann The indentation is actually a copying mistake from my end. I have edited the question now. I am getting two output images currently and they look identical. Sorry for the confusion.But I will try the below approach

Answer (score 3):

Make the render operator and the output path assignment part of the actual for-loop. Demo code using a regular dictionary for the camera locations based on [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23145/31447).

```
import bpy
import os.path

camera_locations = {
    0: (2.576395273208618, -4.465750694274902, 1.094475507736206),
    1: (-0.573695343202619, -1.863753624223357, 1.094235453632562)
}

# Scene variables
scn = bpy.context.scene
cam = scn.camera
output_path = scn.render.filepath

# Iterate through the dict, set the locations and render
for k, v in camera_locations.items():
    # Set the locations
    cam.location = v
    # Assemble the path (.jpg is a placeholder)
    scn.render.filepath = os.path.join(output_path, "cam_{}.jpg".format(k))
    # Call the render operator
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

# Reset the output path to "/tmp/"
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output_path
```

Render output (default scene), output file type set to OpenEXR:

```
/tmp/
├── cam_0.exr
├── cam_1.exr
...
```

Render output of our famous [classroom scene](https://www.blender.org/download/demo-files/) *(make sure to remove the location keyframes of the scene camera before running the script)*:

[image]
*cam_0.png (left), cam_1.png (right)*

---

In case there is no way around a two-dimensional list as provided, I'd suggest use python's build-in [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) as mentioned in the comments, makes the code nearly identical:

```
import bpy
import os.path

camera_locations = [ 
    [2.576395273208618, -4.465750694274902, 1.094475507736206],
    [100.87639527320862, -9.465750694274902, 400.094475507736206]
]

# Scene variables
scn = bpy.context.scene
cam = scn.camera
output_path = scn.render.filepath

# Iterate through the list, set the locations and render
for c, v in enumerate(camera_locations):
    # Set the locations
    cam.location = v
    # Assemble the path (.jpg is a placeholder)
    scn.render.filepath = os.path.join(output_path, "cam_{}.jpg".format(c))
    # Call the render operator
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

# Reset the output path to "/tmp/"
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output_path
```

Note: `object` is an identifier in python hence the different syntax highlighting, I'd suggest use `obj` as variable name and I'd also recommend against string addition for paths, either use `os.path.join()` as above or have a look into the `pathlib` module.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130800/discussion-on-answer-by-brockmann-changing-the-position-of-the-camera-using-pyth).