# How to combine renders from multiple cameras

Tags: rendering, camera

I have 4 cameras in different positions but all of them point to the center of the scene. What I want is to combine all the renders, like film taken from different cameras, combined in one, image from different angles? Is it possible to render all of them at once and combine the render result into one image?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to combine low sample renders?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21806/how-to-combine-low-sample-renders)

Comment: Similar, I don't know that it is a Duplicate though.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8850/how-to-take-images-with-multiple-cameras-with-script

Comment: Related: http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?71693-Multiple-view-point-rendering

Comment: Use the compositor; the details depend on how you want your renders to be combined, though

Comment: We need some sort of reference of what you want to achieve, your current wording could mean several things.

Comment: I have like 4 Kinects that are placed like I said before. each of them have the same POV angle and in the middle of the POV there are like intersection of 4 of them. What I wanna render is this intersection.

Comment: The 3D view branch Dalai has been working on can handle two camera views combined together but 4 cameras boggles my mind a bit.  Maybe you should try using 123D Catch just to see what kind of results you can get from software that is designed to splice images together just to get some idea of what to expect.

Comment: I have seen an explanation of how to do a two color 3-D image mixing two camera images in compositin. i think it used each camera assigned to different render layers and alpha over mixing node. I am out of town and don't have access to my notes/journal, but maybe this will give someone enough of a hint to help fill in details...

Answer (score 12):

You can do this with multiple scenes.

Once you have completed your scene create a new one, selecting Link Objects. This makes the new scene use the same objects as the original, when you move an object it will move in each scene.

[image]

You can either delete the camera in the second scene or just change the active camera for each scene.

If you add a new object after you duplicate the scene, select the new object, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> and choose the scene to link it to.

[image]

Then in the compositor you add multiple RenderLayer input nodes and choose a different scene in each one and composite as you choose. When you render each scene will be rendered automatically.

[image]

[image] I used for the sample here.

Comment: If you want an alternative to the compositor, you can use the Video Sequence editor and each animation would be a strip that has a an Effect Strip / Transform on it.  The transform strip would have things like position.x = -25% and Uniform scale = 0.5

Comment: If I change the render settings after having created the new scenes, is there a way to update them in the other scenes as well?

Comment: @mardy each scene has independent render settings, so either manually set them the same or use a python script if you have a few to do. It would be a simple script so you should quickly get an answer if you make a new question here.

Comment: this is really great (functionality from Blender i mean) and you explained it really brilliant...even i understood it and will use it now! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This only works automatically when you have 4 cameras/renders with the same resolution. 
i cant make it work for animation with 2 cameras side by side.
Like cam1, cam2 has 960x1080 and the final render should have 1920x1080. 
The resolution gets overwritten by the composite scene (cam1, cam2 will have 1920x1080) when you press F12 for render. However if you then click in the node editor the small render button for each render layer it works.

The only general way i found was to render them separately and then combine them in the movie editor.