# View from 3 cameras

Tags: camera

I want to make a animation which will be placed into the holographic pyramid.

1. That means that i have to render my animation from three angles at the same time. How can I do this to record three cameras at once? Maybe some script?

   [image: Picture 1]

Comment: Consider instead setting up your three shots as [Multiple Scenes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23371/45359).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Normally" you are allowed only to ask 1 question (but you may open as many questions as you want). This makes sense because if other people are searching for similar questions your second or third question might not get found because your title cannot reflect 3 questions at once.
I wonder no moderator killed your for that...anyway...

I answer your camera question here:

In your output settings click on "multiview":

[image]

you see here already 2 entries for 2 cameras. Change the suffix to your liking, your camera names should have exactly these suffixes.

If you render now your animation, each frame will rendered as often as you have suffixes/entries and cameras with these names. The images will be named as you define it here.
So e.g. 0001_L.png 0001_R.png 0002_L.png 0003_R.png ...and so on

Comment: Allright i will split my question then and thank you for answer :)