# How to automatically render from several camera angles?

Tags: python, animation, camera

I've got an animation that I want to render from loads of camera angles. How can I write a script to automatically loop through all the cameras and render the scene from each perspective?

Comment: Also see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one

Comment: Yes, you are right. This helped me: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8850/how-to-take-images-with-multiple-cameras-with-script