# How to make faceless sphere

Tags: rendering, mesh, camera

First of all, I'm new to Blender (v2.80). Currently working on AI project for which I need to create my data set. I need to render my object from every possible angle. I found a simple solution over here:
[Script to render one object from different angles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130404/script-to-render-one-object-from-different-angles?newreg=05963af85edf4c40a4a602ea0e952a1b)

---

- *Create a mesh whose vertices are the desired viewpoint positions,
  around your body scan. (It's the sphere, in the illustration, named
  'Viewpoints')*
- *Create one camera, and assign it a 'Track To' constraint ('To': -Z,
  'Up': Y) with the body scan as target*

---

I was trying to achieve that effect, to make that sphere mesh. I just don't know how to make the sphere empty. It looks like this (my object and camera are inside of the sphere):

[image: Blender Sphere]

I'm sorry for making new post about it, I would prefer to comment that post that I'm referring to, but I don't have enough reputation for commenting posts.

Comment: Hi. Glad you liked the solution. To get rid of the faces, Edit Mode,  X (Delete) > Only Faces.

Comment: @RobinBetts no one likes the dolly lol.

Comment: @batFINGER  give it some time.. not counting chickens, here :)

Comment: I liked both solutions! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`bmesh` script.**

Add sphere, remove only faces with `bmesh` in object mode

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add()
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)
bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=bm.faces, context='FACES_ONLY')
bm.to_mesh(me)
me.update()
```

Comment: SE should have a 'Diplomat' badge..