# Is there a way to capture the viewport in Blender the same way as it is on 3DS Max?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I know that by default I can render the viewport and everithing that is in the viewport to be the same as in the render. But, when comparing 3DS Max to Blender, I have certain limitations. In Blender I can render the view-port with vertices/edges/faces to be shown, to be selected, but not the reflections, shadows and such.

Is there a way to render the viewport in Blender as it is in 3DS Max?

Here's how I can do it in 3DS Max:

Viewport look

[image]

Render result of the viewport

[image]

Here is how I can do it in Blender:

Viewport look:

[image]

[image]

Render result of the viewport

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Vladimir Ohh..

Comment: Now I'm confused.. Why are you trying to change it back?

Comment: I had a talk with Matt, where I asked about the issue (http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/how-to-make-my-question-to-be-still-in-use/1240?noredirect=1#comment3544_1240) and I think it would be appropriate to change the question to be in use about Blender. The question was intended to be about 3ds max, but because of a misunderstanding it was "migrated"  so now I updated it to be about Blender.

Comment: @Vladimir probably because your other account asked the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perform an OpenGL render. Simply press the little camera in the *3d view* header or go to *Render > OpenGL Render Image*. It will render out a snapshot of your current view as it is, no cameras or lights needed. You can also change the world settings if the default gray is too bland and also the resolution. More info on the relevant [wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Vitals/Quick_render).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Being a user of both blender and 3ds max, one thing that bugged me at first about blender was that you can only render an image through a camera.  But here are a couple of things I use in blender instead.

- You can use the rendered view mode (as opposed to solid, wireframe, etc.) to preview what a render looks like.  For cycles the number of preview samples are right below the normal render samples setting in *Properties editor > render settings > Sampling*.

  [image: preview samples and rendered view mode]
- In Blender, if you want to actually do a full render, with compositing etc., you have to render through a camera.  You can use the hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> to move the [active camera](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one/) to the viewport and render like normal.
- As [iKlsR suggested](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15212/5705), you can perform an [OpenGL render](http://www.blender.org/manual/render/opengl.html).  But keep in mind that this will render it to essentially look like it does in the viewport, ignoring cycles lighting and materials.

Comment: Viewport render is available in BI too.

Comment: PGmath, thanks for the answer. What do you mean by "rendered view samples"? Sorry, I can't find it.

Comment: Oh, you mean about the sampling of the real-time rendering. Got it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on [iKlsR's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/15212/599), you can go into textured view and enable GLSL get shading from lamps, and enable *Only render* to remove non-rendered elements such as the camera and background:

[image]