# Render image as Blenders viewport

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

Is it possible to have a model rendered as it's seen in the 3D view in Blender?

That means, no shadows, sharp edges and everything illuminated just like the image below?

[image: blender3dview]

Comment: Does the OpenGL option give you what you need? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/opengl.html

Comment: Thanks rcgauer! That's exactly what I need. How do I go about accepting this answer now?

Comment: Max... not much of an answer, but I have posted it so that you can check to accept...

Comment: Also http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15206/is-there-a-way-to-capture-the-viewport-in-blender-the-same-way-as-it-is-on-3ds-m

Comment: Sadly I didn't stumble upon the other question when I searched, but thanks to all for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenGL render should give you what you need. Find it either in the [Info editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/info/introduction.html) > Render > OpenGL Render image or in the 3D viewport header.  Read more about using it - [OpenGL render](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/opengl.html).