# How do I switch the active camera during an animation?

Tags: animation, camera

How do I switch active camera temporarily in the middle of an animation?
Thank you for the link, yes that is what I'm trying to do. But I'm not having much success. It seems that when I try to bind a camera to markers it binds that camera to ALL markers not just the marker I've selected. Note, I pressed A in between to clear all selected markers, then selected the marker I wanted by right-clicking on it. What might I be doing wrong?

Mark clint dion (apologies if I've got that wrong but I have to do this on a phone, its very fiddly and the part that had your name disappeared when I pressed  edit) yes, I appreciate what you are saying but I'm still very much a novice and I don't have all the terminology yet. I try to be clear but I don.'t always realise other possible interpretations exist which might cause confusion. Please forgive me for that
Best,
Gary

Comment: Its not clear what you mean by **temporarily**, I've answered how to temporarily switch away from the active camera, but Im not sure what you mean by **in the middle of an animation** (temporarily could mean - its not saved, or for a brief time only? - please give more info)

Comment: Use markers, as explained here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3503/1853

Comment: Gary C: From what little you've said, I assume you want to have most of the scene rendered from a main camera but would also like to have some portions rendered from a different point of view.  The problem with your question is that there is little to go on.  Providing a proper solution to a question can take some time and effort and people are not going to be very willing to put this effort into answering your question if you have not gone to any effort to clearly explain what it is that you would like to do.

Comment: see http://blendersushi.blogspot.com/2011/11/multiple-cameras-switching-with.html

Comment: Sounds like it's not getting bound. Make sure the mouse is in the timeline when you press Ctrl B

Answer (score 2):

To set a temporary camera, you can *unlock* the camera & layers to the scene (button on the right hand side of the layers).

When this button is not pressed, you can set the active camera (Select camera, Ctrl+Numpad0) *'only for the current view'*.

Comment: I have an issue regarding activating cameras. Could you please take a look at my question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/108064/changing-active-camera-will-yield-an-incorrect-rendering)? I need some urgent help and I think you might be able to help me with it. Really appreciate you.