# camera different position/view on render

Tags: rendering, camera

I position my camera close to my object. In "Camera Persp" I see my object very close. This is what I want.
Now when I hit F12 to render my object, but it always renders from a wrong distance/position further away.

What setting might I have accidentally enabled?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3502/599

Comment: While on camera view, is there a dashed rectangle with everything outside of it darkened?  If not try zooming out until you see it.  The rectangle is the camera, but you can zoom the view in to see just a portion of the camera view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>F12</kbd> always renders the active camera. If you want to move active camera to current viewport position, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>.

After that, you may want to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to fine tune the camera view.

Comment: Also note that you can set the currently selected camera as active by pressing Ctrl Numpad 0.

Comment: didn't know about Shift + F. Whoa! cool!