# How to white out screen with a flare

Tags: animation

I am trying to do a short video intro. The camera will follow a straight path through a circle, then I want the screen to flash completely white.

I have the camera set up to follow the path. Now how do I make the screen flash white?

I just want the screen to go completely white. Doesn't have to be fancy right now. I guess from a circle in the middle that quickly grows to fill the screen.

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: For your first question: Do you want it to look like a real flare, e.g. a more or less random shape that fades from transparent to white while also growing to cover the image, or do you simply want to uniformly fade the image to white?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a camera the active one?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one)

Comment: @cegaton __How__ is this a duplicate of that?

Comment: @someonewithpc it's a duplicate of the second question... that's why two unrelated questions in one post get confusing and should be avoided

Comment: I just want the screen to go completely white. Doesn't have to be fancy right now. I guess from a circle in the middle that quickly grows to fill the screen.

Comment: @cegaton We want to close questions as duplicates based on the *question*, not the answer. Even if a question has the same answer as another question, it's not necessarily a duplicate. For example, while in this case the other answer (switching cameras) may be an answer to the question, there are certainly many other ways this could be done without switching cameras.

Comment: @gandalf3 Did you read the edits? This post originally had two questions, and one of them was specifically about switching cameras.

Comment: @SixthOfFour Ah, my bad.

Comment: @cegaton you make no sense

Comment: @VinceScalia Did you read the edit history?

Comment: @gandalf3 oops. no.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done very easily in the compositor. I am using the Cycles node set in this example.

First, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and add an *Ellipse Mask* node.

[image]

Do the same for a *Blur* node.

[image]

Then hook up the nodes as shown. Animate the Width and Height values by keyframes to animate the effect.

[image]

Depending on your render size you may need to adjust the blur size, but this should get you on the right track.