# How do I set up a hotkey to switch cameras?

Tags: animation, 3d-view, camera, shortcut

To facilitate animating a character I want my main camera to take whatever cinematic view I want and have 2 other cameras I set up to follow location with offset to constrain to look at the same character at different angles. And all I would have to do is for example hit the [C] key now I see the ideal side view hit [C] again and now I see the 3/4 rear view, hit the [C] again and I'm back to my cinematic camera/the one I would use to render with.

So I can do this while on the same frame or at any time. If I had that feature I would use that all the time.

I just need to know how do I set up a hotkey to do that?

Comment: imho not just that: a hotkey can be bound to _one_ command, and there is no such command afaik. You could create a script, though, to do that but also you need to find an available/suited hotkey (C is already doing many things in many modes)

Comment: @m.ardito That is why I said "for example" any key will do, if I need to make a script for this, which I can't, then that is what I request.

Comment: Try [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27098/31447), still works.