# How to install 'Cycle Cameras' addon for 2.8x?

Tags: add-on, camera, installation

I'm using a great addon called ["Cycle Cameras"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27098/3710) made by @CoDEmanX for *Blender 2.79b* which I'd like to use in *Blender 2.8x* as well.

Fortunately there already is an [updated version](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/137359/3710) by @Matthias & @batFINGER. However, I can't get it to work properly. Everytime I try to install it via *User Preferences > Install from File* the addon doesn't show up in the list. I tried to install it in Blender v2.80 and v2.81 without any success.

[image: addon install atempt]

*What am I doing wrong? How to install the updated version properly?*

Answer (score 2):

If the name of the directory of the addon contains "."s and "-"s remove them. Rename the directories name in a way, that it only contains characters a-z and A-Z. Close Blender, reopen blender and check for the addon.

Comment: It worked!!! I placed the file in c:\tmp and give it a short name with just letters..

Answer (score 2):

The following steps work and have been tested in Blender 2.8:

1. Copy and paste the script into a file.
2. Save the file with a `.py` file extension (*lower case*).
3. Open Blender and navigate to the preferences (*Edit > Preferences*)
   [image: Step 3]
4. Open the *Add-on* section by clicking on the button on the left hand side
   [image: Step 4]
5. Click on the *Install* button
   [image: Step 5]
6. Select the python script and click the  *Install Add-on from File* button.
   [image: Step 6]
7. You should now see the add-on in the list and are ready to enable it.
   [image: Step 7]

Answer (score 0):

PS: In order to work with the latest versions of Blender, the addon located at https://github.com/jomachim/Cycle-cameras needs to update its register and unregister functions to read:

```
bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_OT_cycle_cameras)
```

and

```
bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_OT_cycle_cameras)
```

after this it appears to work great in 2.91.