# Shortcut for quickly toggling between cameras (in a similar way the Alt+Tab works for OS tabs)?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, shortcut

Shortcut for quickly toggling between cameras (in a similar way the Alt+Tab works for OS tabs) ?

Assuming the function exists...

If it doesn't, it should lol.

Comment: Hello :). This thread should help https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/27092/78972

Comment: If you are rendering stills you could also set up the scene as an animation with markers for different cameras on different frames that would change cameras going through the frames with the arrow keys. It depends on what you need it for. Providing more context in the question would be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for linking that answer. Now I remember seeing it before, because I searched for the same thing some time ago... before I knew anything about python and before the updated answer for 2.8 was posted.  Hope it works.

Comment: How do you apply the script in order to make it permanent ? Importing through the add-on dialog doesn't work. Running it from the text editor does, but the settings don't get saved and are not present in a new session.

Comment: Should have thought of the markers. Lol I know about the markers only because I was looking for a way to switch cameras, and then I somehow forgot the problem I was trying to solve. Lost the association.