# Camera does not change it's position

Tags: rendering, animation, camera

I'm having this weird problem with my camera in which I can only render from a certain position that is not the one on the camera. It's like the view got detached from the camera and I can't change it.
I can't manipulate it and it always renders in that position. Deleting the camera makes no difference, and there is no hidden camera in the file.
It's not the first time I've had this problem.

Sorry, I can't upload the file since it is now too big.

----SOLVED-----

What happened is, I somehow put another object as my camera.

I solved it by going on Scene Settings (third tab on the Properties window), one of the first fields asks for the camera (and there I had a plane).

Thanks to eromod for pointing out any object can e a camera in Blender.

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and add an image of your screen.

Comment: Do you have any keyframes in the scene?

Comment: Please do not place the solution in the question.  If you have a different answer, please add it down below (or maybe add a comment to an answer that worked for you, noting the changes you needed).  Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have set the object as the "active camera".

In Blender even a mesh can be a camera.

There is a bunch of ways to change it but the shortcut is to select the new

camera and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>

[How can I make a camera the active one?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one)

Comment: Thank you very much, I had no idea this was possible.

Comment: no problem, I knew that because I read it in the Blender Reference Manual. Its my new years resolution, this year, to finish reading it. Im well on my way. https://www.blender.org/manual/

Answer (score 3):

Camera also locks when a keyframe is enabled on the camera.
Solution is to either remove the keyframe, or adjust it on the keyframe if you need. Had this issue and an answer to the OP helped me.

Comment: i had this issue too. the viewport show the correct view but it the render to the first keyframe, the solution is to add new camera