# How can make the camera active?

Tags: camera, scene

How to add an other camera and make it active
How can toggle between the two cameras?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! We welcome your questions, but please take a moment to search and find out if an answer exists already before asking. Keeping questions consolidated helps this site and community by making it easier for people to find answers here.

Comment: @Mentalist why there is no answer section below for this question

Comment: I know that answering your question is too late but the question already has answers in [How can I make a camera the active one?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one)