# How to execute multiple animation node trees over time in a single scene?

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm trying to work out how to execute two seperate node trees (with different falloff settings) within the same scene on the same objects for different camera angles... is it possible to start and stop different node trees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Node Trees

Actually when you have mutliple node-trees they both work at the same time, but the most-recently created one overrides the oldest.

[image: two node trees working together]

This is a completely useless example, but it demonstrates the last created node tree (here 2) will override the z value written by the first (1).

Maybe they are some cool way to make a use of multiple node trees. For example by using booleans:

[image: Booleans]

### Cameras

If you are able to check with a script node which is the active camera (if you are using multiple ones), return true if it is one and false if it is the other, you will be able to switch node tree using the animation nodes.

If you are using only one camera, I would suggest you to switch if the `Time Info` node returns a frame count >= than your angle change:

[image: Animation Camera changing]

[Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one) you can see how to use multiple cameras in one scene