# Why is the camera drifting when following a path and tracking an object?

Tags: camera

Is it possible to put a camera on a path and maintain it at a 1:1 ratio? what I mean by this, is if you look at the image below, it sort of drifts when rotating around..

I have it tracking an empty in the middle of the bed frame.

An example of the drift I'm on about: compare the camera location in the view port on frame 1 compared to frame 70, u see how the camera kind of moves away from the nurbs?

[image: settings]

Thanks

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two cameras on the scene.

You have a marker in the timelilne that controls switching the active camera to camera.001 as the active one at a certain frame.

On the second camera you have a different kind of animated motion.

You can delete the marker or disable the 2nd camera for rendering. You disabled the visibility of it but not the renderability (the camera icon)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the information but my problem is the camera first camera that is moving around in a circle randomly drifts off from the nurbs.. Like I said in the original post.. look at the camera on the nurbs path in frame 1 (its sitting on the path) then go to frame 70 it is slightly off it
http://i.cubeupload.com/UkKRCr.png - on path
http://i.cubeupload.com/oJGQ7E.png - off path

Comment: Just select the camera and press Alt G to clear the camera placement.

Comment: Heh, can't believe it was that simple haha, thanks a lot dude.