# How to choose a 1 camera out of 2 cameras in the scene to align using CTRL + ALT + 0?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

I have a simple problem. I have 2 cameras in the scene and I would like to align only of them when I press CTRL + ALT + 0.

At the moment, one of the camera is set and I want the new camera to align with CTRL + ALT + Z but my first all set camera moves instead the added new camera.

Any suggestions?

W

Comment: You need to make the camera you want to align the active camera, see the answer here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. Select the camera you want to align to the view port.
2. View > Cameras > Set active object as camera
3. Align the view you want in your view port and press CTRL + ALT + 0

It will align the camera made active to the view you wanted.

Thanks to Dan for pointing another thread that helped me get my answer.

Good Day,
W