# Render view incorrect (Maybe)

Tags: rendering, animation, camera

I have a file that includes Camera Animation.  It renders the animation fine or a single frame after selection.

What I want to do though is manipulate my viewport view and render that as a single image.

What happens is I get the animated camera view at whatever frame it is on and not the viewport view.

I tried using the view-viewport render image option but that does not do a full render.

I also tried adding another camera but still it takes the animated one...

Please advise what I am doing wrong, and YES I am relatively new to this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a camera the active one?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one)

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks so much. That did the trick.

Comment: Oh, hold on... That did the trick but even though I select render Image, it goes and renders it for each frame in the animation (or steps thereof)  how do I turn off the animation part whilst I render a single view?