# Render doesn't match camera

Tags: rendering, camera, eevee-render-engine

i'm new to blender, but I was messing around with simple deformers and made this scene. When I want to render the image, the camera seems zoomed in. Can't find anyone with similair problems..

[[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Blender SE! Have you done any compositing, using the scale node? It would also be helpful if you provided your .blend file, preferably using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hard to guess what's wrong. Most likely there is another camera in your scene which is the active one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3503/31447 If that doesn't solve your issue I suggest share a *minified version* of your blend (eg. replacing your geometry with some cubes or icospheres) with us.

Comment: It's not just zoomed in.. there are completely different scene elements in the image?

Comment: I've not done anything with the compositing if I remember correctly. Also, Brockmann, that didn't solve it, I will post the blend file now. And Robin, yeah that is the weird part

Comment: You are using elements nested within other collections, check the renderabily switch (camera icon) within the hierarchy tree in the outliner.  Lastly make sure you don't have any video strips in the video sequence editor.

Comment: I fixed it, when I applied all the simple deformers to the object, the artifacting stopped and the rendering was done successfully. Thanks anyways guys