# How do I make the camera snap to position

Tags: animation, camera

I want to be able to have the camera move somewhere instantly, is this possible?

Like when the camera jumps to a different angle in a different shot.

P.S I'm very new to animating, so, please be patient.

Comment: you can either move the camera or switch from a camera to another

Comment: Use markers to move from one camera to the next https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one/3503#3503

Comment: Thank you, that will definitely help!