# Camera Align to View - CTRL-ALT-0 - does some really weird stuff

Tags: camera

When I click on the Camera button, something really funky happens. Also, at random points, the hood from my lamp will disappear. I have even deleted the camera and added a new one and I can't make the camera align with the view.

My main problem here (aside from those symptoms) is that I can't set up any kind of render shot because the camera (either existing or new) will not behave.

Thanks.

I would love anyone's help. Thanks.

Comment: Select the camera and try `Crtl` + `Numpad 0`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a camera the active one?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one)