# How to Take different shot's with one camera in different places

Tags: camera

I was watching this tutorial  online, and i realized that it was using blender 2.79, and what the person did was switching between shots with one camera while animating the camera. However, in blender 2.8 it doesn’t really happen correctly, because  the camera can only have one view direction throughout. I really only want to use one camera on my animations, so how can i make different shots? (how they did it was to go one single frame forward, and then move the camera to the desired  view, so when you play it, the camera appears to suddenly change view, however when i do it, it seems to override the pervious code).

What i mean is that the view angle does not change, so from the start is looks north, but in the second view angle it looks south. But instead what the animation does is remove the fact that is looks south when i play it.

[image]

If you play the animation, the zoom in is suppose to be on the cube, and the jump is suppose  to be a different  angle

Comment: You can use multiple cameras using markers: [How can I make a camera the active one?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3503/31447) or just animate one camera per frame basis...

Comment: sounds like you didn't keyframe the rotation between your two camera positions

Comment: @wilks what exactly do you mean?

Comment: ...also you should edit your previous question, not post another one

Comment: @wilks oh ok sorry about that

Comment: i mean that you have to insert a keyframe for both location and rotation (for both angles), otherwise blender has no way of knowing which way you want the camera to be pointing

Comment: Oh ok thank you!

Comment: Please don't ask the the same quetsion twice. Edit the original post instead .https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/105442/dhruv

Answer (score 1):

One solution: if you want to focus on a single object, use a object constraint (on the camera object).  It will keep the camera rotated to look at the object (your Cube).

[image]

result: [image]

Another was @wilks suggestion to not only key in the location of your camera, but also the rotation of your camera (where it points to):

[image]

That shows up in the Dope sheet:  [image]
[image]