# How to "activate" some camera, i.e. view through it?

Tags: camera

Suppose, I have some camera in the scene and I want to view scene throug this camera. How to do this?

First I read this should be done by `Ctrl Numpad 0`. It worked once then stopped.

Next I read this can be done via selecting desired camera in `Scene` panel. This also worked once then stopped.

Here is the UI

[image]

As you see, camera si highlighted and also selected in `scene` pane. Also you see that camera is seen from aside, so we are not viewing through it. Pressing `Ctrl-NumPad0` does nothing.

Comment: Just to add to the current answer - to move the camera while looking through it check *Sidebar (N) > View > Camera to view*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a camera the active one?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one)

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> sets an object as an active camera, but is not intended to change the point of view itself.

In order to view from the active camera, just press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> or on the 3D Viewport's menu choose  *View*> *Viewpoint* > *Camera*.

Or select *View* > *Cameras* > *Active Camera*