# Is there a way to move specific keyframes from the layout timeline directly into the video editor?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Currently, I only know that I should export out the frames as an image sequence to my computer and then import the image sequence back into Blender's video editor. It's fine for simpler animations but now I have multiple cameras and would want them to be rendered in cycles.

Is there a way to move specific keyframes from the timeline in the Layout section directly into the Video Editor without having to export them out first?

Thank you.

Comment: There are two things you can do (if I understood your Q) ... You can add a Scene strip into VSE timeline and specify camera object to be seen through under strip properties, so you can combine views ... Or directly in default timeline add markers to to let blender switch active camera object. ... Both explained here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one

Comment: Thats awesome! Thanks for sharing this post.