# How to set multiple camera views in one scene?

Tags: 3d-view, camera

Is it possible to have several different views of one scene and set them as named "presets"?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one?rq=1

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139/how-do-i-cycle-through-the-camera-views/141#141

Answer (score 15):

**Yes**.

You can create new cameras with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>*> Camera*, or you can just duplicate an existing camera with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

To name them, enter a name in *3D view > Properties region > Item*, and optionally enable  *Name* in *Properties editor > Object > Display* to display the name in the 3D view:

[image]

The active camera (the one used when you press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> or render) is the one with the solid triangle.

To set a camera as active, select it and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>, or select it in the scene panel with a search-able list drop down:

[image]

Another useful shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>, which snaps the active camera to the current view.

You can lock the transforms of the camera object to prevent moving them in the 3D view:

[image]

However you can still move them with the transform sliders in the interface.

Comment: Great. Thank you. I didn't mention it, but can one "lock" the cameras/aka "presets", so that they NEVER move? I know one can lock the view to camera, but that still allows scene changes.

Comment: @user961976 Something like this? (see my edit)

Answer (score 8):

In addition to gandalf3's answer, you can also cycles though views using the timeline and markers. To do this, add a marker to your timeline by pressing <kbd>M</kbd> while hovering over the timeline. Next, select your first camera and marker, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> while hovering over the timeline. This will bind your camera to that marker. You can then repeat these steps for each camera in your scene.

If you place your markers on consecutive frames, you can uses the arrow keys to cycles between views.

**Marker usage guide:**

Move marker: <kbd>G</kbd>

Delete marker: <kbd>X</kbd>

Rename marker <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd>

[For more on markers see the wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/#Markers)

Comment: Ingenious bypass to stubborn UI ;-)