# Cycle through camera views

Tags: python, camera

My scene has multiple cameras. Is there a way to cycle through camera views with a hot key, or a script?

Comment: You can use these shortcuts: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14666/3127

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8850/how-to-take-images-with-multiple-cameras-with-script

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one/3504#3504

Comment: @GiantCowFilms It looks like the OP wants to cycle through the views in the viewport.  That question is talking about rendering from multiple cameras.

Comment: No, It is specifically about the view port, or at least the answers are anyway...

Comment: posted answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one