# Multi Cams at the same time in the same Scene

Tags: 3d-view

I really would like to set a Scene on which I have 2 or more Views that represent 2 or more Cameras at the same time but I'm not able to reach my targert.

Each time that I select a different cam, all the views are updated to the last one. :

[image: example]

Is it possible to have 2 or more views aligned with 2 or more cams at the same time in the same Scene?

Again, is it possible to have:

View 1 aligned with Camera 1 even if I select Camera 2

and

View 2 aligned with Camera 2 even if I select Camera 1

at the same time?

Ps.
I'm not in an animation,
I do not want to render,
I want only to setup the environmet

Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a camera the active one?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/how-can-i-make-a-camera-the-active-one)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. Please read the question again. He's asking something different.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14663/how-to-set-multiple-camera-views-in-one-scene

Comment: Having the same problem. I see there is no clear answer at the moment. It appears (unfortunately) a view can be locked only to the active camera, hence you cannot see your scene thru two cameras at the same time. However [this is possible using the video editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4Y8Z.png) (activating preview, and overriding camera). In some cases this could be a good solution. The previews will follow the camera animations if any.

Answer (score 4):

In Blender 2.8 you can now select a "Local Camera" to look through per window. Use the 3D view properties panel N-Key. Select a camera that isn't the Scene camera and turn on "Use Local Camera".

[image: Use an alternate "local" camera]

This can be useful if you are rendering 2 concurrent views of the same animation.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to render the different views, you can just set up windows with user perspective instead of a camera view.

Is there a reason you want to use cameras? (If you want to render a specific view after setting up your scene, you can snap the camera to that view with ctrl + alt + Num0).

[image: Blenderscreen]

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that no matter how many cameras you have in a scene, Blender will only show the view from the active camera, the one you clicked most recently.

The closest you can get to what you're asking about is the QuadView. (Display the numeric properties panel (n) open the Display section, and click Toggle QuadView.)