# How to quickly select the 3D viewpoint among Front, Top, Left, etc., and customized ones?

Tags: 3d-view, interface

I thought the 3D-view viewpoint could be set equally according to predetermined directions (six standard views: Left, Top, Right...) and also camera directions. But it doesn't seem to be the case:

[image]

It turns out the correct procedure to select a camera viewpoint is two-fold, as explained in the selected answer to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3502/15265):

1. Switch the 3D-view mode to "camera" (in the menu above, or using the shortcut <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>)
2. If the current "active camera" is not the one you want, select the correct one using the scene "camera" setting. You may also select the camera object in the 3D view and make it the active camera (using the submenu shown above or the shorcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd>), but this can be a bit difficult in general, as the camera can be hidden by actual objects.

[image]

To make it short, I'm surprised by this quite laborious procedure, which has also the side effect of changing the camera used for rendering ("active camera"), something that seems unrelated to working in the 3D view:

Looking at addons shipping with Blender, I see none able to simplify this.

**Question**: Is there a method to simplify the 3D-view viewpoint selection, where any viewpoint, standard (e.g. Front) or user-predefined (e.g. a camera, but not limited to cameras) can be selected in a couple of clicks?

If not, what would be the script required to add this feature to Blender's view menu?

Comment: There's a getaround in GiantCowFilm's answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14663/how-to-set-multiple-camera-views-in-one-scene)

Comment: @RobinBetts: Thanks, an ingenious way to deal with a stubborn UI, I must say :-)