# seamless mesh placement

Tags: modifiers

Is it possible to place meshes in a seamless way on a plane, I have made some tests with the array modifier but it didn't work

Here is my setup[image]
The part of the fish that are not in the square should be in the opposite edge of the square 
Here is what I try to do (this version is eye balled so it is not seamless)[image]

Comment: You can use 9 orthographic cameras (3 rows x 3 columns) upon your scene, then merge the 9 rendering using the compositor. I think the cam need to be ortho as if not, say, top and bottom won't have the same point of view. This way, there is no problem placing the meshes. There could be some solution around this also https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145175/render-animation-with-multiple-views-of-the-same-scene/145564#145564

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ive had this issue before too and solved it like this:

1. Have the plane 2m x 2m in size
2. Apply the particle system
3. Join the particles to the plane
4. making it tile

(option 1)
 Duplicate the original plane and move it 2m to the left/right/top/bottom and corners

(option2) use 2 array modifier, uncheck relative, check constant distance and set it to 2m on X and the other 2m on Y, now the middle one has all the overlapping parts.

that way the middle plane has all the overlapping parts

if you have multiple particle system, apply them all at the same time, join them together with the plane

Now you can proceed with the baking