# How to control Camera Movement for long and complicated shots?

Tags: animation, camera, bezier-curves

So I'm setting up camera animations for very long continuous shots with lots of twists and turns.

Following the advice of some Youtube tutorials I'm working with (follow path and track to contraints and) two paths - one for the camera linked to an empty, another one for a target empty the camera is tracking to.

That's working fine as long as I work my way through the animation in a strictly linear fashion.

However, the position of the camera and its target aren't inherently linked to each other (or defined by static/absolute values in any way) but to the ever changing percentage of each path's length. So any subsequent extension of paths or adjustment affecting either one of the path's lengths messes up all the once fine-tuned relations of the camera position to the target empty. That's incredibly frustrating and impractical.

Am I missing something (like breaking up the paths into multiple sections and animating the "influence" values of multiple empties?) or is there a better, controlled way to go about this? I'd like to keep working with paths though.

Any help or links to suitable tutorials greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7qyW1G350g , but it is not using paths.

Comment: Consider using another camera. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77616/making-cuts-from-camera-to-camera  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72277/how-swap-views-between-multiple-camer